# angular 9 loadchildren doesn't load css, js, image file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular9

**This question already asked but it doesn't work for me, am new in `Angular 9`.**

I have `admin` and `catelog` folders in my `Angular 9` project. For `admin` folder I try to load all `admin-components`, and `catelog` folder I try to load `catelog-components`.

`CSS`, `js` and `images` not loading in `catelog` check below image
[image]

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './admin/helper/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './admin/pages/login/login.component';

const adminModule = () => import('./admin/pages/pages.module').then(x => x.PagesModule);
const catelogPageModule = () => import('./catelog/pages/catelog.module').then(x => x.CatelogModule);

const routes: Routes = [
  // catalog url
  { path: '', loadChildren:catelogPageModule },

  //admin url
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren:adminModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

  // otherwise redirect to home
 // { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**catelog.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { CatelogRoutingModule } from './catelog-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CommonComponent } from './common/common.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CommonComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CatelogRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class CatelogModule { }
```

**catelog-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';

import { CommonComponent } from './common/common.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component:CommonComponent,
        children:[
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
export class CatelogRoutingModule { }
```

**app\catelog\pages\common\common.component.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Title</title>
      <!-- CSS here -->
      <link href="/assets/catelog/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
     
      <!-- header-area -->
      <header>
         <!-- menu-area -->
      </header>
      <!-- header-area-end -->
      
      <!-- Main content -->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <!-- Main content -->

      <!-- footer-area -->
    <footer class="dark-bg pt-55 pb-80">
        copyrights
    </footer>
    <!-- footer-area-end -->
    <!-- JS here -->
    <script src="/assets/catelog/assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/catelog/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**My folder structure:**

[image]

> `Admin` folder `CSS`, `js` and `images` working properly, but `catelog` folder `CSS`, `js` and `images` not loading.

Please help me to short out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be putting whole `<html><body>...</body>` inside your component template. The `common.component.html` should look like:

```
<header>someHeader</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>some data</footer>
```

So without `<html>, <body>, <srcipts>` etc.
If you need to load bootstrap.css - you can do it in global `styles.scss` file, and for loading js files you can use angular.json ( there is a place to place additional js over there )

Comment: thanks for your answer, If I import css in `styles.css` it will affect `admin` design. Please check my assets folder here https://ibb.co/gS49Q3w. In `admin` I used `bootstrap v4` and `catelog` am using `bootstrap v5`

Comment: But in admin `app\admin\pages\common\common.component.html` I putting whole `html`, admin working please check this code: https://ibb.co/RPBYNQt
page: https://ibb.co/ZYNnZ4q

Answer (score 1):

You should follow what Panda already suggested but I will modify little bit the answer based on the css issue you are facing

Structure your project routes as per following
Main page

```
<html>
  <body>
     <header-comp/>
      <app-comp></app-comp>
     <footer-comp/>
   </body>
 </body>
```

At app component html

```
<router-outlet/>
```

At app component module
Add app component, add routes to two lazy loading modules home and admin plus extra route entry that redirects default route to home module

Now since home and admin are two modules each will have its own home page , that home page is is the default entry of the home/admin routing module with sub children routes to other module pages and its html looks like that

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In the module home page component definition add the desired boatstrap css version

```
@component({
 selector:'home-app-comp',
 html:'<router-outlet/>',
 styleUrl:[path to css file]
 })
```

The whole idea is based on having some sort of nested routes where each module main page loads desired bootstrap version and acts as a parent container for the rest of the module pages